# polarity of unmarked battery with zero charge

Tags: batteries, polarity

This battery has the following equivalent part numbers [HMA2104, HTPA7W, BKB191210/4](http://www.gtspower.com/GTS/media/GTS/Spec%20Sheets_US/HMA2104-M-~-Spec-sheet-~-TWR-~-14-03-24-~-US.pdf), but I cannot find any information on the polarity/pinout of the 3 pins.

Is there some safe way to figure out the polarity of the battery? Maybe the IV characteristic for some small currents/voltages.

Comment: If the battery has zero charge, then the cells are dead - you won't be able to charge it anyway. Toss it! If you want to replace the cells, you need to open it up anyway.

Comment: Opening the case may provide markings on the cells inside.

Comment: It could be two 3.6V NiMh cells in series with the centre tap used for charger balancing

Comment: You don't have access to a charger for the battery? I mean a factory charger? Maybe it would be easier to take it apart and put two lithium batteries in there.

Comment: I don't have a charger for the battery. Even if the cells in the battery are dead, I would like to know the pinout so that I can power the device that goes with the battery.

The case looks like it's ultrasonically welded, so it would be nice to avoid opening the battery.

Comment: Do you have a lab power supply with settable voltage and current limits?

Comment: Maybe you could buy a charger and look for polarity markings there, bring your voltmeter.

Comment: I found the online spec sheet for that battery at:  http://www.gtspower.com/GTS/media/GTS/Spec%20Sheets_US/HMA2104-M-~-Spec-sheet-~-TWR-~-14-03-24-~-US.pdf  Since it contains the phone number of the company, why don't you call them and ask?   For Pricing or Additional Information Contact: 
Global Technology Systems, Inc.
550 Cochituate Road Framingham, MA 01701
US: 1.800.267.2711 

 EU: 00800.5390.5390
www.GTSpower.com